# Replacing elements in ndarray based on condition

Tags: python, numpy

I have bi-dimensional array, like that:

```
f_vars = np.array([[0,4],
                   [0,2],
                   [3,-1],
                   [3,4],
                   [1,-1]])
```

I am trying to replace some of the elements based on few conditions, as follow: if an element is equal to -1: leave it as is, if it is less then given variable (for example 2): increase by 1. If it is equal to 2, make it 0. If it is between two given variables (for example 2 and 4), leave it as is. If it is equal to the second variable, make it 0. If it is higher than the second variable: decrease with one.

So far I have tried the following cycle:

```
for i in np.nditer(f_vars):
    if i < 2: f_vars[i] = f_vars[i]+1
print(f_vars)
```

This is only the beginning of my cycle, but the result is quite unexpected:

```
[[ 3  7]
 [ 0  2]
 [ 3 -1]
 [ 3  4]
 [ 2  0]]
```

It is modifying only the first and the last element for some reason, and the modification is not by adding 1, but quite different.

Any advice will be highly appreciated.

Comment: `f_vars[f_vars<2] = f_vars[f_vars<2] + 1` - [https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using logical indexing:

```
f_vars[f_vars < 2] += 1
```

will give you:

```
[[1 4]
 [1 2]
 [3 0]
 [3 4]
 [2 0]]
```

as expected. You can continue in the same manner for applying more conditionals. You might make use of `np.logical_and` to achieve multiple conditions. Take care of the order you apply the conditions and if you find it confusing, an `if-elif-else` statement would be the easiest. The `np.nditer` indexing is done like this:

```
for x in np.nditer(f_vars,op_flags = ['readwrite']):
    if x == -1:
        continue
    elif x < 2: 
        x[...] += 1
```

So, you have to set `op_flags = ['readwrite']` and index through the `i[...]` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

There will be some ways you can use masked arrays together. Let work on when you want to find values that are equal to `-1`. So, mask will be as:

```
mask_equal_neg1 = f_vars == -1
# [[False False]
#  [False False]
#  [False  True]
#  [False False]
#  [False  True]]
```

If you want the `True` indices be unchanged, so one way is to use `~` before `mask_equal_neg1` or [`np.invert`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.invert.html) to invert the Booleans to adjust it for indices you want change:

```
~mask_equal_neg1
# [[ True  True]
#  [ True  True]
#  [ True False]
#  [ True  True]
#  [ True False]]

f_vars[mask_equal_neg1]
# [-1 -1]

f_vars[~mask_equal_neg1]
# [0 4 0 2 3 3 4 1]
```

For using these masks in combination, you can use `&` (and) or `|` (or):

```
mask_equal_neg1 & ~mask_equal_neg1
# [[False False]
#  [False False]
#  [False False]
#  [False False]
#  [False False]]

f_vars[mask_equal_neg1 & ~mask_equal_neg1]
# []

mask_equal_neg1 | ~mask_equal_neg1
# [[ True  True]
#  [ True  True]
#  [ True  True]
#  [ True  True]
#  [ True  True]]

f_vars[mask_equal_neg1 | ~mask_equal_neg1]
# [ 0  4  0  2  3 -1  3  4  1 -1]
```

In the above code, we get all `True` or `False` because we used two masks which are inverse to each other.
The total masks needed are as follows:

```
mask_equal_neg1 = f_vars == -1
mask_lower_2 = f_vars < 2
mask_equal_2 = f_vars == 2
mask_bigger_2 = f_vars > 2
mask_lower_4 = f_vars < 4
mask_equal_columns = f_vars[:, 0] == f_vars[:, 1]
mask_equal_bigger_column = f_vars[:, 0] > f_vars[:, 1]
```

**If we want to use masks repeatedly for in_place replacements, so we must consider their using order i.e. the masks must be used in order of the needs.**

Now, in your case assuming indices with value equal to `-1` will be never changed, so we use its inverse in combination with the other masks. For the next step we want to find values `<2` (step 2) and add by `1`. Since, the next step (step 3) that is to find values equal `2` will have conflict with the previous condition (i.e. `<2` *step 2*) when we faced to values `=1` (if we have values `=1` in step 2, so those values will be add by `1` and became `2`; the 3rd step will works on this value), we must consider the order of using masks. If we have:

```
f_vars = np.array([[0, 4],
                   [0, 2],
                   [3, -1],
                   [3, 1],
                   [1, -1]])
```

Now consider **order** in 2 various conditions:

1. step 1 then step 2

```
mask_equal_neg1 = f_vars == -1
mask_lower_2 = f_vars < 2
f_vars[~mask_equal_neg1 & mask_lower_2] += 1
# [[ 1  4]   <-- column 1
#  [ 1  2]   <-- column 1
#  [ 3 -1]
#  [ 3  2]   <-- column 2
#  [ 2 -1]]  <-- column 1

mask_equal_2 = f_vars == 2
f_vars[~mask_equal_neg1 & mask_equal_2] = 0
# [[ 1  4]
#  [ 1  0]   <-- column 2
#  [ 3 -1]
#  [ 3  0]   <-- column 2
#  [ 0 -1]]  <-- column 1
```

2. step 2 then step 1

```
mask_equal_neg1 = f_vars == -1
mask_equal_2 = f_vars == 2
f_vars[~mask_equal_neg1 & mask_equal_2] = 0
# [[ 0  4]
#  [ 0  0]   <-- column 2
#  [ 3 -1]
#  [ 3  1]
#  [ 1 -1]]

mask_lower_2 = f_vars < 2
f_vars[~mask_equal_neg1 & mask_lower_2] += 1
# [[ 1  4]   <-- column 1
#  [ 1  1]   <-- column 1 & column 2
#  [ 3 -1]
#  [ 3  2]   <-- column 2
#  [ 2 -1]]  <-- column 1
```

assuming we do the first one (i.e. *step 1 then step 2*), so we continue from the modified array:

```
f_vars = np.array([[1, 4],
                   [1, 0],
                   [3, -1],
                   [3, 0],
                   [0, -1]])
```

Next step is to avoid changing the values between 2 and 4, so we need the invert Boolean array:

```
~mask_equal_neg1 & ~mask_bigger_2 | ~mask_lower_4
# [[ True  True]
#  [ True  True]
#  [False False]
#  [False  True]
#  [ True False]]

f_vars[~mask_equal_neg1 & ~mask_bigger_2 | ~mask_lower_4]
# [1 4 1 0 0 0]
```

Now we can go to the last two conditions which need to consider the needed order again. If we want to change values equal to the second variable to 0 and then decrease with one the values higher than the second variable, so if:

```
f_vars = np.array([[1, 1],
                   [1, 0],
                   [3, -1],
                   [3, 0],
                   [0, -1]])
```

so, we can specify the mask for rows which satisfy the condition and modify the first column (index --> 0):

```
mask_equal_columns = f_vars[:, 0] == f_vars[:, 1]
# [ True False False False False]
f_vars[mask_equal_columns, 0] = 0
# [[ 0  1]   <-- column 1
#  [ 1  0]
#  [ 3 -1]
#  [ 3  0]
#  [ 0 -1]]

mask_equal_bigger_column = f_vars[:, 0] > f_vars[:, 1]
# [False  True  True  True  True]
f_vars[mask_equal_bigger_column, 0] -= 1
# [[ 0  1]
#  [ 0  0]   <-- column 1
#  [ 2 -1]   <-- column 1
#  [ 2  0]   <-- column 1
#  [-1 -1]]  <-- column 1
```